# centos pyodbc stopped working. Error: pyodbc.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_From_Object

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc, undefined-symbol

As I needed to add some libraries to Python2.7 on CentOS, I decided to rebuild Python. However, since I've done this, pyodbc doesnt work anymore and shows the following error when trying to import pyodbc

```
 >>> import pyodbc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyodbc.py:3: UserWarning: Module pyodbc was already imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyodbc.pyc, but /mnt/fastArray0/user/Roel/Development/django/pyodbc-3.0.7 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyodbc.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyodbc.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /root/.python-eggs/pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/pyodbc.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject
```

I reinstalled pyodbc, reinstalled all dependencies but the issue persists. Also, I checked the new libraries I added to Python but i really doubt that packages like pytz won't affect pyodbc at all.

Furthermore, all other libraries are still working fine. It is just pyodbc which really doesn't like to work anymore.

Comment: Can you confirm you remembered to install all of these packages? (sudo yum install) freetds freetds-devel unixODBC unixODBC-devel

Comment: Yes, I just checked and all packages are still present.

Comment: Also, pyodbc works fine for python2.6. It only has issues with python2.7

Comment: I believe I have it figured out. This is what I've had to do on CentOS / RedHat. Can you try pip installing like this: "pip install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip" (without the quotes, of course). If that's what you're doing, let me know and I'll dig a bit deeper. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found out what was wrong. I had build Python the wrong way. I used the flag `--enable-unicode=ucs4` while I shouldnt have used it. pyodbc doesn't like this at all so that is why it kept on crashing.